# Как преобразовывать заглавную букву в главную и обратно при поиске как в гугле?

Tags: php

Пишу велосипед подскажите как приобразовывать заглавную букву в главную и обратно при поиске например в поиске могут писать паркинсон но правильность его написания Паркинсон , как при вводе паркинсон искало Паркинсон если это нужно а если болезнь то с маленькой буквы и чтоб не преобразовывало, чтоб обяснить правильно в гугле ищет с любой буквы

```
    if (!function_exists('mb_ucfirst') && extension_loaded('mbstring'))
{

  function mb_ucfirst($search, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
  {
    $search = mb_ereg_replace('^[\ ]+', '', $search);
    $search = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($search, 0, 1, $encoding), $encoding).
         mb_substr($search, 1, mb_strlen($search), $encoding);
    return $search;
  }
}

$search = 'паркинсон,  болезнь';

$search = mb_ucfirst($search);
```

Comment: `mb_strtolower` перевести всё и вся в нижний регистр и проблема вроде как уходит)

Answer (score 2):

Как один из самых адекватных вариантов, делать это за счет СУРБД, далее привожу концептуальный пример, т.к. БД вы не указали:
`SELECT id, status, name FROM various_table WHERE LOWER(target_name) = LOWER(name);`

Соответственно, что бы вам не передали и что бы у вас не хранилось в базе, вы ищите совпадение двух строк в нижнем регистре.

---

Однако, отвечая прямо на ваш вопрос, первую букву строки в верхний регистр: `mb_ucfirst($str);`, в нижний: `mb_lcfirst($str);`.

Comment: Если вы про `mb_`, то у задающего вопрос уже это в коде имеется. Поправил.

Comment: да, про mb.. Да, у ТС есть, но, т.к. без mb_  тоже есть функции, есть вероятность что ими и восопользуются и скажут что не работает)